# Regular expression with optional group wrapping multiple groups returns undefined for branches not taken

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in JavaScript that returns the first quoted or non-quoted word in a string without the quotes (if present).  For example:

```
'"quoted phrase" followed by text' => 'quoted phrase'
'phrase without quotes followed by text' => 'phrase'
```

My regular expression currently is this: `(?:"([^"]*)"|([^"\s]+))`

However, what I'm noticing is that the output always includes two match groups, one that's always undefined, presumably from the branch that wasn't taken (i.e. it's the first match if the first word is not quoted, second otherwise).

What kind of changes can I make to avoid getting the `undefined` match group and still get the quote-stripping behavior?

NOTE: The words are NOT strictly "word-only" (e.g. alphanumeric) characters.  They can include non-word characters, just not the `"` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want using just the regex.  Other regex flavors have power features like the Branch Reset Group (which causes capturing groups in each branch to start with the same number):

```
(?|"([^"]*)"|([^"\s]+))
```

...or they let you use the same name for more than one group:

```
(?:"(?<token>[^"]*)"|(?<token>[^"\s]+))
```

...but JavaScript has nothing.  Of all the regex flavors associated with programming languages (Perl, Python, Java, etc.), JavaScript is the most lacking in useful features.  You just have to go through all the groups and find the one that's not `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `^` (Start anchor) to match the first word and simply use `\w+` to match the word also i think you don't need the main group :

```
"([^"]*)"|(^\w+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB6sQ9/1)

Comment: That regex still gives me `undefined` values in the output.  `'"quoted phrase" followed by text'.match(/(?:"([^"]*)"|(^\w+))/) ==> ['"quoted phrase"', 'quoted phrase', undefined]`

Comment: @Spig what about removing the outer group?`"([^"]*)"|(^\w+)`

Comment: Still have `undefined` in output.  `'"quoted phrase" followed by text'.match(/"([^"]*)"|(^\w+)/) ==> ['"quoted phrase"', "quoted phrase", undefined]`

Comment: Is the `match` is a correct method for this case? maybe you need to change it or also you can loop over your list and just keep the elements that have a valid bool value!

Comment: I'd considered that option but wanted to check to see what the appropriate way to handle multiple matching groups within the regex before turning to outside of the regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting extra matches because of the nested groupings you have defined inside your regular expression. The corrected expression should be 
`(?:"[^"]*"|[^"\s]+)` which would produce the following for your inputs (without string quotes)

```
'"quoted phrase" followed by text' => "quoted phrase"
'phrase without quotes followed by text' => phrase
```

Comment: I want to keep the quote-stripping behavior.  `(?:"[^"]*"|[^"\s]+)` will retain the quotes (if present).

Comment: I am not sure you can achieve that with only a regular expression. Your current regex does not strip off the quotes either from my tests. Or does it? if so, how?

Comment: There are three results.  The first is the match of the outermost group (which will include everything that matched the whole expression, including quotes) while the second two are from the inner groups I've defined.  Neither of the results from the inner groups will have the quotes.  I was looking for a way to prevent getting the `undefined` from the branch not taken.  Looks like it can't be done in JavaScript.